# dart upload file error: FormatException: Bad UTF-8 encoding 0xbf

Tags: upload, dart, httpserver

Here is my server side dart code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http_server/http_server.dart';

void main() {
  HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.LOOPBACK_IP_V4, 8080).then((server) {
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      if (request.method.toLowerCase() == 'post' && request.uri.path == '/upload') {
        HttpBodyHandler.processRequest(request).then((body) {
          HttpBodyFileUpload fileUpload = body.body['file'];
          File file = new File('aaa');
          file.writeAsBytes(fileUpload.content, mode: FileMode.WRITE).then((_) {
            request.response.close();
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

and my error is:

```
Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: FormatException: Bad UTF-8 encoding 0xbf
Stack Trace:
#0      _Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:534)
#1      _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:334)
#2      _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:330)
#3      _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:89)
#4      _handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:119)
#5      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1020)
#6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341)
#7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:270)
#8      _StreamController&&_SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:578)
#9      _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:453)
#10     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:410)
#11     BoundMultipartStream._parse.reportData (package:mime/src/bound_multipart_stream.dart:161:34)
#12     BoundMultipartStream._parse (package:mime/src/bound_multipart_stream.dart:318:28)
#13     BoundMultipartStream.BoundMultipartStream.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:mime/src/bound_multipart_stream.dart:111:24)
#14     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1020)
#15     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341)
#16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:270)
#17     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:122)
#18     _ForwardingStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:86)
#19     _handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:154)
#20     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1020)
#21     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341)
#22     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:595)
#23     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:711)
#24     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:671)
#25     _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#26     _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#27     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:126)

#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:820)
#1      _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#2      _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:126)

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I used postman to make a post, I chose form-data and add a key called file, value is a txt file.
after send my post to dart server, i got this exception.
is there something wrong with the post ? or the dart code ?
I'm really new to dart, please help me out...
thank you.

Comment: I think it's because my txt file include some Chinese characters. For pure english file, the upload operation was ok. But what should I do if I want to upload Document with Chinese characters?

Comment: Are you sure the .txt file you are uploading is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Hi Tom, I'm really stupid. I thought it was utf-8. I use chrome to open it, and it's gb18030..... Thanks for the tip.